# Como crear un pico blanco de la parte superior

Tags: android, android-layout, design

He estado viendo ejemplos de diseños y este me ha gustado muchisimo, quisiera saber como realizar el pico de en medio de la carta blanca.

Desconozco el nombre de la propiedad, lo intente buscar en internet pero no eh encontrado nada

[image]

Comment: no creo que sea con una libreria o algo similar, una forma de hacer eso es <View> que tengan esos colores como background y colocarlos dentro de un RelativeLayout por ejemplo

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a intentarlo!

Comment: Buenvenida Vanessa, realiza tus preguntas en base a [ask], no olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer su funcionamiento, basico, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: traingle design]

Podrías realizar algo como esto, en tu `layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/part1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/purple">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/triangle"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/white_triangle"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_description" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/part2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Para el pico blanco utilicé un drawable llamado `white_triangle.xml` con el siguiente código tomado de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517589/making-a-triangle-shape-using-xml-definitions) pregunta:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="90%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@color/transparent" android:width="30dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@android:color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Puedes encontrar el código completo en el siguiente [link](https://github.com/israteneda/StackOverflow/tree/master/TriangleDesign).